# how to set position of vertex names in igraph network

Tags: r, igraph, names, vertex

I need to set the position of vertex labels inside or right next to them. Which parameter should i change in plot to change that?

i've tried to change vertex.label.cex and vertex.label.dist parameters but labels still located in the corner of the plot and look messy.

```
plot(g, 
 vertex.color= "yellow",
 vertex.size = degree(g)*0.3,
 vertex.label=names,
 vertex.label.cex = degree(g)/1000,
 edge.width= 0.5,
 vertex.label.dist=0.1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had the right idea with `vertex.label.dist`. You just used too small a value.

Since you did not provide your graph,  I will illustrate with a random graph (and some modifications to your plot statement to match this graph).

```
library(igraph)

set.seed(1234)
g = erdos.renyi.game(15, 0.2)
plot(g)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
set.seed(4321)
plot(g, 
 vertex.color= "yellow",
 vertex.size = degree(g),
 edge.width= 0.5,
 vertex.label.dist=0.1,
 margin=-0.2, 
 main="vertex.label.dist=0.1")

set.seed(4321)
plot(g, 
 vertex.color= "yellow",
 vertex.size = degree(g),
 edge.width= 0.5,
 vertex.label.dist=1,
 margin=-0.2,
 main="vertex.label.dist=1")
```

[image: Graph with unshifted and shifted labels]

Notice that with the larger value of `vertex.label.dist` the labels are visibly offset.